Case expression to override another case expression and input the same value for 2 rows
Employee is assigned to multiple business units and based on business units an 'Individual type' is derived.
Individual type
Point 1. Considered to be individual type 'IA' if they don't have another business unit from point 2 and is only in DIST or CS-IA, GS-IA
Point 2. Considered to be individual type 'EMP' if an employee is in any of these business unit - CI-CLMS, CI-DIST , GS-CLMS, GS-DIST, PL-CLMS, SFCLMS, PI-CRC, PI-DRC, PI-FLDSLS, PI-HODST , EXTLV. Anyone with these BU's should be 'EMP' regardless of them having other business units like DIST or PI-IA/CI-Clms
Point 3. Considered to be individual type 'CWK' if an employee is in any of these business unit - PI-IA, CI-Clms or PI-temp and not in business units from** point 2.**
select 
 distinct
    i.lastname,
    I.firstname,
    I.empnumber, 
    b.businessunit,
case 
when b.businessunit = 'DIST' or b.businessunit in ('CI-IA_1')
    THEN 'IA'
when b.businessunit in ('PLCLM8-BI') 
        or b.businessunit in ( 'PI-FldSls2') 
        or b.businessunit in ('PI-HODst4' ) 
        or b.businessunit in ('EXTLV')
    THEN 'EMP'
When b.businessunit in ('CI-ClmsTA') 
    THEN 'CWK'
END
as 'individualtype'
from
individual i left join businessunit b
on i.internalid = b.internalid
WHERE I.status IN ('Active','Inactive','Pending') 
      AND B.status = 'ACTIVE' 
      and i.empnumber = '1617413' 

Result I'm getting now:



lastname
firstname
empnumber
businessunit
individualtype




Doe
John
1617413
DIST
IA


Doe
John
1617413
PI-FldSls2
EMP



Expected Result:



lastname
firstname
empnumber
businessunit
individualtype




Doe
John
1617413
DIST
EMP


Doe
John
1617413
PI-FldSls2
EMP



individual table



lastname
firstname
empnumber
internalid




Doe
John
1617413
1


Line
Sam
2034567
2


Dot
Jane
1256789
3


Doe
James
2768902
4



businessunit table



empnumber
businessunit
internalid




1617413
DIST
1


1617413
PI-FldSls2
1


2034567
EXTLV
2


2034567
PI-FldSls2
2


2034567
PI-HODst4
2


2034567
PLCLM8-BI
2


1256789
DIST
3


1256789
CI-ClmsTA
3


2768902
DIST
4


2768902
CI-IA_1
4




Please provide example records for the tables individual  and businessunit

Please simplify your example by removing the business units that are not needed to demonstrate the problem.

Took out all the other business units not present in the table sample and updated the query

@BartMcEndree added the sample data for individual and businessunit table

Please provide column internalid in your example data

as 'individualtype' -> Please don't use single quotes to delimit entities - use [square brackets] or, if you really want these to look like string literals for some reason, or want to use standards-compliant and non-deprecated syntax, at least use "double quotes".

@BartMcEndree added the internalid, it's a unique identifier that's used to join. In case the employee number is null in any scenario

Please provide column status in your example data

I was finally able to reproduce your example in a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/vOPbxSMd

Your data is not consistent. Several of the business units referenced in your source data are not included in your logic. Also, you have two conflicting rules for "CI-CLMS"/"CI-Clms".

In order to get EMP as an individual type value the businessunit must satisfy this part of the case expression:
when b.businessunit in ('PLCLM8-BI') 
        or b.businessunit in ( 'PI-FldSls2') 
        or b.businessunit in ('PI-HODst4' ) 
        or b.businessunit in ('EXTLV')
    THEN 'EMP'

DIST is not in this list.

Point 2 should be your first case. All the other cases stipulate "if they don't have another business unit from point 2"

Even if I move point 2 as the first case. The results are still the same as what I have currently. When I get to the scenario for John Doe having business unit from Point 2 and  Point 1 then the row with Point 1 business unit should be overwritten with the Individual type from Point 2. I'm getting confused as to how to do that :/

I think you absolutely "need" a mapping table that holds the type for each emp number, to avoid horrible, extremely complex queries. Then in future you just need to fill this table. I would make this table as simple as possible and use a trivial JOIN.
So the table could for example be like this:
CREATE TABLE individual_types 
(empnumber varchar(100),
individualtype varchar(100),
description varchar(100));

The description column is optional, you could save there an information what EMP, IA etc. means. You could also add a foreign key to the emp number if you want.
Then your query will be quite simple and produce the expected result:
SELECT 
  i.lastname,
  i.firstname,
  i.empnumber, 
  b.businessunit,
  t.individualtype
FROM
  individual i LEFT JOIN businessunit b
    ON i.internalid = b.internalid
  INNER JOIN individual_types t
    ON i.empnumber = t.empnumber
  WHERE 
    i.status IN ('Active','Inactive','Pending') 
    AND b.status = 'ACTIVE' 
    AND i.empnumber = '1617413';

The only question is how to fill the mapping table. The most tricky part is the initially insertion.
For future emp numbers, you can use your application (clean) or a trigger (ugly) to fill the table and simply enter the logic there.
In order to fill the table correctly for the already existing emp numbers, you need to write an insert command with the exact logic you want.
I'm not entirely sure if I understand your intended logic correctly, but you should be able to fix it if I made a mistake. It should be something like this:
INSERT INTO individual_types (empnumber, individualtype)
SELECT
  i.empnumber,
  CASE WHEN
        COUNT(
          CASE WHEN b.businessunit IN ('CI-CLMS', 'CI-DIST', 'GS-CLMS', 'GS-DIST', 
                                       'PL-CLMS', 'SFCLMS', 'PI-CRC', 'PI-DRC', 
                                       'PI-FLDSLS','PI-HODST','EXTLV') THEN 1 END) > 0
        THEN 'EMP'
        WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(
          CASE WHEN b.businessunit IN ('DIST','CS-IA','GS-IA') THEN 1 END) 
        THEN 'IA'
        WHEN COUNT(
          CASE WHEN b.businessunit IN ('PI-IA', 'CI-Clms', 'PI-temp') THEN 1 END) > 0
          AND COUNT(
          CASE WHEN b.businessunit IN ('CI-CLMS', 'CI-DIST', 'GS-CLMS', 'GS-DIST', 
                                       'PL-CLMS', 'SFCLMS', 'PI-CRC', 'PI-DRC', 
                                       'PI-FLDSLS','PI-HODST','EXTLV') THEN 1 END) = 0
        THEN 'CWK'
        ELSE 'Other'
        END
FROM 
  individual i LEFT JOIN businessunit b
    ON i.internalid = b.internalid
GROUP BY
  i.empnumber;

If you have the optional description column, I would update it after the insertion.
See this sample fiddle that shows the idea is basically working. Adjust the insert command if necessary.
Notes: Of course, you could also produce the result without creating a table (that's why I wrote "need", not need).
In this case, you would use the query not to insert rows to your mapping table, but in a CTE that you join to your main query.
Or you could only create another column in your existing table rather than creating a whole table.
But I think a mapping table is clever and makes things easier.
You could, if you create a mapping table, also do this in other ways, as for example shown in this answer.
There are lot of options how to do what you want and it's up to you to decide what's the "best". Depends on your use case(s).

As I understand your problem, if any of the business units for a given individual fall into the "EMP" group, then that individual is considered an "EMP". Otherwise, if any of the business units for that individual fall into the "IA" or "CWK" groups, that individual is considered a "IA" or "CWK", respectfully.
Your logic does not address the possibility of an individual having both "IA" and "CWK" business units, but I'll assume that "IA" supersedes "CWK".
To get your desired results, you need to:

Map all of the business units to individual types. Although this can be done with an embedded case expression, it would be much better to have a some kind of lookup table that defines this mapping. This reduces code clutter and should improve maintainability.
For each individual, we need to scan all of the business units and mapped individual types for that individual and pick the select the top preferred individual type for whatever mix we might have. This can be done with a combination of a case expression, window functions, and conditional aggregation.

The business unit to type mapping would be something like:
CREATE TABLE businessunittype (
    businessunit VARCHAR(50),
    businessunittype VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO businessunittype
VALUES
    ('DIST',       'IA'),
    ('CS-IA',      'IA'),
    ('GS-IA',      'IA'),
    ('CI-CLMS',    'EMP'),
    ...,
    ('EXTLV',      'EMP'),
    ('PI-IA',      'CWK'),
    ('CI-Clms',    'CWK'),
    ('PI-temp',    'CWK')

The query would be something like:
select
    i.lastname, i.firstname, i.empnumber, b.businessunit, bt.businessunittype,
    case
        when count(case when bt.businessunittype = 'EMP' THEN 1 END)
             over(partition by i.empnumber) > 0 then 'EMP'  -- Point 2 
        when count(case when bt.businessunittype = 'IA' THEN 1 END)
             over(partition by i.empnumber) > 0 then 'IA'   -- Point 2
        when count(case when bt.businessunittype = 'CWK' THEN 1 END)
             over(partition by i.empnumber) > 0 then 'CWK'  -- Point 3
        else 'Other'
        end AS individualtype
from individual i
join businessunit b
    on b.internalid = i.internalid
left join businessunittype bt
    on bt.businessunit = b.businessunit
order by i.empnumber, b.internalid

There are likely other ways this logic could be refactored, such as wrapping the individualtype logic up in a CTE or subquery and then joining it with other data in the final select. The businessunittype table could have other forms, such as having flag bits instead of a text field to indicate the mapped type.
Results (with some missing business unit mappings applied and extra test data):



lastname
firstname
empnumber
businessunit
businessunittype
individualtype




Dot
Jane
1256789
DIST
IA
EMP


Dot
Jane
1256789
CI-ClmsTA
EMP
EMP


Doe
John
1617413
DIST
IA
EMP


Doe
John
1617413
PI-FldSls2
EMP
EMP


Line
Sam
2034567
EXTLV
EMP
EMP


Line
Sam
2034567
PI-FldSls2
EMP
EMP


Line
Sam
2034567
PI-HODst4
EMP
EMP


Line
Sam
2034567
PLCLM8-BI
???
EMP


Doe
James
2768902
DIST
IA
IA


Doe
James
2768902
CI-IA_1
???
IA


Contract
Worker
9900001
PI-IA
CWK
CWK


Contract
Worker
9900001
PI-temp
CWK
CWK


Mixed
IA/CWK
9900002
GS-IA
IA
IA


Mixed
IA/CWK
9900002
PI-temp
CWK
IA


Unknown
Unknown
9900003
PLCLM8-BI
???
Other



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
